# PHP extracting data from inbetween delimiters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
$heading = '';

$text = '
        *Heading 1* Text **SubHeading 1A** More Text **SubHeading 1B** Text**Subheading 1C**
        *Heading 2* Text **SubHeading 2A** More Text **SubHeading 2B** Even more text**Subheading 2C**
    ';

    if(preg_match('#*(+?)#*',$text,$result));
        $headings .= $result;

    if(preg_match('#**(+?)#**',$text,$result));
        $headings .= $result;

    echo $heading;
```

From $text, how could I possibly extract what's between the `*` so that what in between one `*` is a heading and whats between 2 `**` is a subheading?

The output I'm trying to achieve is like this:

```
Heading 1
    SubHeading 1A
    SubHeading 1B
    SubHeading 1C

Heading 2
    SubHeading 2A
    SubHeading 2B
    SubHeading 2C
```

I did put it a great deal of effort, but my mind cannot think of anything anymore. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = array();
if (preg_match_all('/([*]+[^*]+[*]+)/', $text, $matches))
        $result = array_map(function ($v) {
                return str_replace('*', '  ', rtrim($v, '*'));
        }, $matches[1]);

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/QxusQT)

Comment: You are close. The only problem is, there is other text below each heading and subhead, which I did not include when I posted the question. I need to pick out only the Headings and Sub Heading (the ones in the `==`) and not the text below them. Right now it selects even the text below them. Can something that selects only the headings and not the text be done?

Comment: @jmenezes Have you tried to use this code? It extracts only the headings as you desire. See demo in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `*` and in your regex and use `.+?` to match 1 or more characters in input (lazy). Also you have misplaced reges delimiters here:

```
#*(+?)#*
```

and here:

```
#**(+?)#**
```

**You need to use:**

```
#\*(.+?)\*#
```

and:

```
#\*\*(.+?)\*\*#
```